# Add a column and update it in same stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, alter-table

if I have a stored procedure say

```
CREATE PROCURE w AS

ALTER TABLE t ADD x char(1)

UPDATE t set x =1
```

Even when it lets me create that stored procedure (if I create it when x exists), when it runs, there is an error on the UPDATE statement because column x doesn't exist.

What's the conventional way to deal with this, it must come up all the time?  I can work around it by putting the UPDATE inside EXEC, is there another/better way?

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth are you modifying the table schema in s sproc?

Comment: quelle horreur huh?  It's a judgement call, maybe a bad one. The table I'm altering is one into which raw data is uploaded.  And there will be different tables with different shemas.  In all cases, they'll need these two columns added that aren't in the source.  The columns are "actual tax id" and "is the taxid a programmatically contrived one".  So the having the step in the s proc is more a way of communicating to the humans using the s proc that "this is the point of no return, you must make up the taxid number here if you didn't get a valid one".

Answer (score 4):

`ALTER TABLE` in the context of 1st TRANSACTION and `UPDATE` in the context of 2nd:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE w
AS
   BEGIN TRAN
      ALTER TABLE ..
   COMMIT

   BEGIN TRAN
      UPDATE ..
   COMMIT
END
```

Comment: Sounds attactive but I can't make it work: 
CREATE PROCEDURE p 

AS 

BEGIN TRAN 

ALTER TABLE t 

ADD x CHAR (1) 

COMMIT 

BEGIN TRAN 

UPDATE t 

SET x = 1 

COMMIT 

If I use "END" I get a syntax errror. If I successfully create it the procedure, I still get the same errror if "x" doesn't exist at run time (and would get another error if it did exist)

Comment: @TortTupper: It seems that's a limitation of SQL Server. How about file a bug on MS.Connect? I would upvote it. My workaround: create 2 separate SPs and call them turn-by-turn. Or create a 3rd which will call 1st and 2nd

Comment: @TortTupper: Another idea why does it happen. SQL Server can't create a SP accessing a not-yet-existed column during SP creation. So maybe your task is impossible yet.. (

Comment: Well, for me it worked to put the update statements into Exec('WITH blahblhablah....'), but I did have single quotes already in my update statement, so that came up ugly, and my point is to try to make the process self-explanatory, so I may well break it into two separate sps.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding a column like this and then updating its value, you can add a column with a default value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE w AS 

ALTER TABLE t ADD x char(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT abc DEFAULT 1
```

Comment: Elegant solution! But will work, I guess, only if new column doesn't allow NULL

Comment: Thanks, but 1 isn't actually the value i want in there, I want to update the new column to a value from a "FROM" clause; I just had 1 in my example as a placeholder to show something simple that caused the error.

Comment: than first get the value in varible and than use here select @@variable=1 ALTER TABLE t ADD x char(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT abc DEFAULT @@variable may work for you

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is that your update is being validated against the existing table before it will execute the create for your procedure.

If you're committed to this all you have to do is make sure that the table doesn't exist when you create/alter the procedure, which takes the parser down the deferred name resolution path due to the non-existent objects.

After the procedure is created, then you can create your table.

I'm assuming your process drops/creates the table already or you really wouldn't really need a procedure like this anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should add a GO statement just after the Create.

Sql server will send the create so, and then your update will work fine.